# rich:ToolTip appears to be consuming all events on rich:datatable

Tags: java, jsp, richfaces

When i add a rich:toolTip to the table below it stops the filter working as if the tool tip is consuming all events fired by the table. Can anyone see why?

The table works fine normally and the `tableItem` does have the `getToolTip()` method. The tooltip does display. I am using RichFaces 3.3.1.

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{backingBean.itemList}"
                    var="tableItem" rows="#{searchCriteria.numRowsToDisplay}"
                    reRender="ds" id="searchTable" rowKeyVar="row"
                    >

                    <rich:column headerClass="smallFilter" sortable="true"
                        sortBy="#{tableItem.idAsInteger}" filterBy="#{tableItem.id}"
                        filterEvent="onkeyup">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{msgs.idColumnHeader}" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{tableItem.id}" />
                        <rich:tooltip >
                            <h:outputText value="#{tableItem.tooltip}" />
                        </rich:tooltip >
                    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://community.jboss.org/message/613801 Richfaces bug in chrome.